# Python Tokenizer, sentence gets cut off at newline character

Tags: python, tokenize

I am trying to build a tokenizer with python, I think it is going on pretty well but there is one problem that I cannot seem to solve. I'll try to be as elaborative as possible:
This is the text I am trying to tokenize (txt.gz file):

"Het Franse danceduo Daft Punk hangt hun kenmerkende helmen aan de wilgen .
De dance-act stopt er na 28 jaar mee .
In een bijna acht minuten durende video kondigde het tweetal het afscheid aan .
Een woordvoerder heeft het nieuws aan entertainmentblad Variety bevestigd , maar wilde verder niet uitweiden over de reden van het stoppen .
In de video die vanochtend online kwam zijn Thomas Bangalter en Guy-Manuel de Homem-Christo met hun helmen te zien .
In de bijna dertig jaar dat ze actief waren , hebben ze lange tijd hun identiteit geheim weten te houden .
De twee staan tegenover elkaar en lopen vervolgens uit elkaar terwijl een onheilspellende wind klinkt .

And this is the output I am getting:
" Het Franse danceduo Daft Punk hangt hun kenmerkende helmen aan de wilgen .
dance-act stopt er na 28 jaar mee .
kondigde het tweetal het afscheid aan .
reden van het stoppen .
Homem-Christo met hun helmen te zien .
waren ,  hebben ze lange tijd hun identiteit geheim weten te houden .
onheilspellende wind klinkt "

This is my code:

```
import sys
import re
import gzip

def tokenizer(data):
    tokens = re.compile('[^ ].*?[.!?]')
    list_of_tokens = tokens.findall(data)
    print(list_of_tokens)

    string_token = ""
    string_token = string_token.join(list_of_tokens)
    string_token = re.sub('([.,!?()])', r' \1 ', string_token)

    return string_token

def main(argv):

    with gzip.open(argv[1], 'rt') as f:
        data = f.read()


    print(tokenizer(data))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(sys.argv)
```

Comment: What output are you expecting?

Comment: Hi thanks for answering, sorry I got it confused.

This is the input: 
AFP NOS Nieuws • Cultuur & Media • vandaag, 16:42
Danceduo Daft Punk stopt na 28 jaar

Het Franse danceduo Daft Punk hangt hun kenmerkende helmen aan de wilgen. De 
dance-act stopt er na 28 jaar mee. In een bijna acht minuten durende video 
kondigde het tweetal het afscheid aan. Een woordvoerder heeft het nieuws aan 
entertainmentblad Variety bevestigd, maar wilde verder niet uitweiden over de 
reden van het stoppen.

Comment: and this is the expected output (with a correct program):

Het Franse danceduo Daft Punk hangt hun kenmerkende helmen aan de wilgen .
De dance-act stopt er na 28 jaar mee .
In een bijna acht minuten durende video kondigde het tweetal het afscheid aan .
Een woordvoerder heeft het nieuws aan entertainmentblad Variety bevestigd , maar wilde verder niet uitweiden over de reden van het stoppen .

Comment: So basically you want to strip this part out of the string? `AFP NOS Nieuws • Cultuur & Media • vandaag, 16:42 `

Comment: No not really, as you look at my output and the expected output you can see that in my output only part of each line gets shown whereas in the expected output full sentences get shown. If you take a close look at both you will notice.